# How to create a responsive video layout with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a website where I'll need to add a video. the video will be triggered using a javascript click event, the video is contained with an iframe.

The video when invoked needs to fit the height and with of the parent div. I'm using bootstrap layout to help me create a responsive layout.

I followed an example online but for some reason the video does not fit the entire width of the parent div.. I'm using the container fluid class with the col-**-12 grid layout.

I've included a jsfiddle link with an example of what I have implememnted.

https://jsfiddle.net/JuiceJay/rt9L69ya/6/

```
<div class="container-fluid remove-padding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="vid_thumb embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="bio_vid">
            <h1> A leader in the world of photography</h1>
            <span id="play-btn"><img src = "http://www.rockinrranch.com/wp-content/themes/rockinr2013/images/play-button.png" alt = "thumb"/></span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

h1{
    position: relative;
    top: 240px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em !important;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
    -moz-transition: .2s ease-in;
    transition: .2s ease-in;
}

  `.vid_thumb{
            background-image: url('https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/thumb-1920-82317.jpg');
            background-attachment: local;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            -ms-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px !important;
            max-height: 400px !important;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            filter: grayscale(60%);
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(60%);
            border: 1px solid green;
        }

        .vid_thumb img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto; 
            margin: 0 auto;
        }


        span img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%; 
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #play-btn{
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            opacity: 0.3;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            display:none;
        }

        .vid_thumb:hover #play-btn{
            display: block;
        }

        .vid_thumb:hover h1{
            display:none;
        }

        #play-btn:hover{
            opacity: 1;
        }

  .remove-padding{
    padding: 0px !important;
  }

document.getElementById('bio_vid').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.innerHTML = '<iframe class = "embed-responsive-item" src=   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6uSHOp2Uj0" width="100%" height="400px allowfullscreen="false">';

  if (document.getElementById('bio_vid').ended) {
      document.getElementByTagName("iframe").style.display = 'none';
   }
```

});

Somehow, if i use the col-**-6, and dive the grid in two, it fills the width of either but not col-**-12.. I've even tried using the bootstrap embed-responsive-16by9.

Or any help on ditching boostrap and implementing a whole new and easier method.

I would also like to know how to detect the end of a video through iframe using javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry but webdevelopment is trial and error, this is just throwing a 'I want this' over the fence. You did some work, ok, but imho you just turn too soon too fast to throwing it on SO

Comment: How do you expect that to work? Just like an image, the video has an inherent aspect ratio -- you can't reshape it to a different height/width without distorting its contents.

Comment: @Rienk I was on it since last night, but thanks for your response.. duskwuff I did it with the col-**-6, so i assumed it could have been done with the col-**-12.. but thanks alot, I will try finding a video with a wider aspect ration.